# Active Admin - Dropdown menu with same resources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I have a picture model and I want to know if it is possible for me to create a drop down menu where both resources are pictures with different names.

My picture model has an attribute 'gender', which can either be male or female.

I want to create the following structure

```
Picture
  ->Male
  ->Female
```

male.rb

```
ActiveAdmin.register Picture do
  menu parent: 'Pictures', :label => "Male"
```

female.rb

```
ActiveAdmin.register Picture do
  menu parent: 'Pictures', :label => "  female"
```

I changed the resource retrieval code also.

```
controller do
def scoped_collection
  end_of_association_chain.where(gender: 'M')
end
end
```

This is the menu structure that I get

```
Picture
  ->Male
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should help you:

```
ActiveAdmin.register Picture, as: "Male"
ActiveAdmin.register Picture, as: "Female"
```

Take a look at the related [docs](https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/blob/6bde1f57ec5f9b724c21e5af146678f4ade839bc/docs/2-resource-customization.md#rename-the-resource) for details.